# Issues copying site into local machine

Tags: wp-config, localhost, backup, xampp

I am working on a Wordpress site that is stored on a goDaddy server. I want to migrate a copy (backup) of the site on my local machine so that I could edit the php files without changing with the actual site.

I install XAMPP and copied all of the files from the homeDir in the goDaddy server onto htdocs/wordpress folder I created in XAMPP. I created a database and connected and set up the wp-config file accordingly. It seems to connect to the database fine.

**Here is the problem**
When I visit the site (localhost/wordpress) it shows the default wordpress theme and content as if I were to install wordpress for the first time. 
The backup homepage looks like this on goDaddy:

[image: What the site actually looks like]

After moving the backup to the my locahost, this is what the site looks like:
[image]

Another problem is that I cannot even login through wd-admin. I've tried loging in through the user and pass in the users table in the database, but it doesn't accept the credentials.

Any help? I'm new to Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have not imported the backup of database (sql file) to new database you have created in your localhost. Also after importing the database to local server you will need to replace the live site URL with new localhost URL at all instances in local database.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy the files from goDaddy all sorts of oddities from that host may come with it. If I were you I would do a clean install.

1. [Download WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/) and install it
2. Check which plugins and themes you have running on your goDaddy. Download fresh ones and install them.
3. Export all content from goDaddy (under tools -> export) and upload it locally.
4. Copy the uploads folder from goDaddy to your local install.
5. This leave the options of your widgets, themes and plugins to transfer. If there are few of them just set them anew. There's a plugin for [importing/exporting theme customizer options](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/). Other options can be exported with [this snippet](https://digwp.com/2014/04/backup-restore-theme-options/), but it's rather cumbersome.

Or you could try the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/), which I have no experience with.